# R: `geojson_read()` read UTF-8 file on Windows results in weird characters in `@data` slot

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, geojson

When I download some open data using download.file, I can see that æ, ø and å are encoded correctly when I open the temp.geojson-file.

```
url <- "http://wfs-kbhkort.kk.dk/k101/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=k101:p_pladser&outputFormat=json&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326"
download.file(url, destfile = "temp.geojson")
```

However, when I import it, the æ, ø and å turn into weird characters.

```
library(geojsonio)
p_pladser <- geojson_read(x = "temp.geojson", what = "sp")
p_pladser <- geojson_read(x = "temp.geojson", what = "sp", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
p_pladser <- geojson_read(x = "temp.geojson", what = "sp", encoding = "latin-1")
p_pladser <- geojson_read(x = "temp.geojson", what = "sp", encoding = "UTF-1")
```

I don't understand where the encoding goes wrong? When downloading the data into a file, shouldn't I be able to define the encoding I want myself?

How do i get the characters to show correctly in R, as they are in the `temp.geojson` file?

Note: I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: If I had to guess - you're on Windows, right?

Comment: Unfortunately yes - The joys of the coorporate world...

Comment: @gitzhuoer I had already tried that prior to your answer, as you can see in my second code-block. But thanks for your suggestion anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UTF-8 problem on Windows is very hard to deal with. Basically, you can convert the UTF-8 file to natively encoded and read converted file or read the UTF-8 file and convert the returned R object.

## Explain

The encoding problem happens when you read the downloaded file using `geojson_read()`.

It depends on where you download the data. In the url, the string after '?', i.e. "service=WFS&...&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326" is options passed to the website. For example, "outputFormat=json" means you want the `.json` file. For some website, you may choose the encoding, maybe something like "encoding=UTF-8". You need to refer the documentation of your target website for detailed information.

You can try the solutions below, either is ok.

## Solution

### 1

I use the Simplified Chinese edition (`localeToCharset()` gives `"CP936"`)

```
utf8 <- readr::read_lines('temp.geojson')
native <- enc2native(utf8)
writeLines(native, 'native.geojson')

p_pladser <- geojsonio::geojson_read(x = "native.geojson", what = "sp")
```

check the result

```
as.character(p_pladser@data$p_type)[998]
[1] "Uafm<U+00E6>rket parkering"
```

### 2

```
p_pladser <- geojsonio::geojson_read(x = "temp.geojson", what = "sp")

for (column in colnames(p_pladser@data)) {
    if (is.factor(p_pladser@data[ , column])) {
        char <- as.character(p_pladser@data[ , column])
        Encoding(char) <- 'UTF-8'
        p_pladser@data[ , column] <- as.factor(char)
    }
}
```

check the result

```
as.character(p_pladser@data$p_type)[998]
[1] "Uafmærket parkering"
```

I'm not familar with your data so I can only find that `p_pladser@data` contains no english characters. If you find any other place also contains no english characters, you need to convert it like what I did:

1. retrieve value (maybe need `as.character()`)
2. `Encoding(..) <- "UTF-8"`
3. assign back (may need `as.xxx()`)

## more

Actually, I have just spent one week to dive into the encoding problem on Windows. You can refer https://github.com/viking/r-yaml/issues/38 for more information.

You can consider Ubuntu system if the encoding problem really hurt you.

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine? Because when I do exactly the same I get:
> head(p_pladser$p_type)
[1] UafmÃ¦rket parkering UafmÃ¦rket parkering UafmÃ¦rket parkering UafmÃ¦rket parkering UafmÃ¦rket parkering UafmÃ¦rket parkering
9 Levels: AfmÃ¦rket parkering AfmÃ¦rket skrÃ¥parkering, 30Â° AfmÃ¦rket skrÃ¥parkering, 45Â° ... UafmÃ¦rket skrÃ¥parkering, 90Â°

Comment: I voted it back up. I appreciate your help, and don't know who voted it down. Maybe it was because, you suggested something, I had already tried.

Comment: Thank you so much for voting my answer up.

Comment: Ah, Windows and encoding. I hate this combination to the guts. I've walked this path many times before and hated it every time.

Comment: Yeah, fight with encoding problem on Windows is the on the of **best** ways to waste life. Just witch to GNU and everything will be okay.

Comment: Yeah, fight with encoding problem on Windows is one of the best ways to waste life. Just witch to GNU and everything will be okay.